# Android : Remove the vertical padding from the popup menu items

Tags: android, padding, menuitem, popupmenu

I'm trying to remove the vertical padding between each item of a PopupMenu.

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, this.findViewById(R.id.popup_button));
```

I specified the item height, but I did not find the item padding attribute :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.Popup</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/content_item_height</item>

        <!-- How can I remove the vertical padding between each item? -->
    </style>
```

[image]

The item height is represented by the red rectangles.

Comment: i didn't understand what padding you are talking about. Please share the screenshot of the padding and explain your problem a bit.. Otherwise you can get downvotes from other members.

Comment: @PrakharSrivastava I understand. I hope it's clearer that way. :)

Answer (score 5):

I really don't know why, but doing this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/content_item_height</item>
</style>
```

instead of :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.Popup</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/content_item_height</item>
</style>
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Congrats! you fixed it1